# Form routes to the wrong action causing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I created an itinerary web app that allows a user to upload itineraries and 'download' other users itineraries into their profile. For whatever reason instead of my download button routing to the downloads controller, it routes to the itineraries controller and breaks my app. I can't seem to figure out why - hope you can help.

Here's the download button on the itinerary show page:

**Itineraries/show.html.erb**

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  <% unless current_user.downloaded?(@itinerary) %>
    <%= render 'download' %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <p>
  You need to be logged in to download this.
  </p>
<% end %>
```

The partial rendered should route to the download controller:

**itineraries/_download.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(current_user.downloadeds.build) do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :downloaded_id, @itinerary.id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Download", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**DownloadsController**

```
class DownloadsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user
  def create
    #download id is established in the download form
    @itinerary = Itinerary.find(params[:downloaded_id])
    current_user.download(@itinerary)
    redirect_to @itinerary
  end
```

Instead it routes to the itineraries controller and this returns the following error:

> ActionController error - param is missing or value is empty: itinerary

**itineraries_controller.erb**

```
  def create
    @itinerary = current_user.itineraries.build(itinerary_params)
    #@user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @itinerary.save
      # render the page with the users itineraries
      flash[:success] = "Your itinerary has been added!"
      redirect_to request.referrer || current_user
    else
      #show the add itinerary page
      flash[:error] = @itinerary.errors.full_messages
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

**config/routes**:

```
  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users

  resources :itineraries do
    resources :reviews
  end

  resources :downloads, only: [:create, :show]

  mount PdfjsViewer::Rails::Engine => "/pdfjs", as: 'pdfjs'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `form_for`, there's nothing telling it to go to a different controller, so you have to add that.  You can supply this kind of option:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.downloadeds.build, url: {controller: downloads}) do |f| %>
```

This should change the controller that the download will be sent to.  You can supply hash arguments (e.g. `url: { controller: 'controller_name', action: 'action_name' }`), a route helper (e.g. `url: download_path(@download)`), or an explicit URL (e.g. `url: "http://example.com"`).  The format that you choose is based on your needs and preference.